# Complexity of a simple code

Tags: time-complexity

We have the following pseudo code and I'm trying to figure out the complexity of them. So I need to count the number of operations.

```
 i:=1;j:=1;    1 
    while(i<n ) and (j<n) do n+1+n+1
    i:=i+1 ; j:=j+1; 2
    end while
```

So The complexity is O(2n+5) =O(n).Are the operations on the side correct?
What if we had `while(i<n ) or  (j<n)` do instead of `while(i<n ) and (j<n)` do. How would the complexity change?

Comment: complexity here is O(N) in all cases you mentioned

Comment: Are the operations on the side correct?

Comment: no, in first line you're doing 2 operations, but count them as 1, in second line your loop actually from 1 till n-1